# How to send parameters with webview react-native?

Tags: react-native

This is my **Class**:

```
class MyWeb extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <WebView
             source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
             style={{marginTop: 20}}
             // how to send parameter?
          />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please utilize the formatting tools to format your code properly. Your question is included as a comment, please take that out.

Comment: how to get all javascript alert in webview from uri i am visiting

Answer (score 0):

use **props**, [here is the document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html)

i advise you to read all the basic and guide part of the doc

Comment: tell me how to get all javascript alert in webview from uri i am visiting